# Randomize the splitting of data for training and testing for this function

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I wrote a function to split numpy ndarrays `x_data` and `y_data` into training and test data based on a percentage of the total size.

Here is the function:

```
def split_data_into_training_testing(x_data, y_data, percentage_split):
    number_of_samples = x_data.shape[0]
    p = int(number_of_samples * percentage_split)

    x_train = x_data[0:p]
    y_train = y_data[0:p]

    x_test = x_data[p:]
    y_test = y_data[p:]

    return x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test
```

In this function, the top part of the data goes to the training dataset and the bottom part of the data samples go to the testing dataset based on `percentage_split`. How can this data split be made more randomized before being fed to the machine learning model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there's a reason you're implementing this yourself instead of using `sklearn.train_test_split`, you can shuffle an array of indices (this leaves the training data untouched) and index on that.

```
def split_data_into_training_testing(x_data, y_data, split, shuffle=True):
    idx = np.arange(len(x_data))
    if shuffle:
        np.random.shuffle(idx)

    p = int(len(x_data) * split)
    x_train = x_data[idx[:p]]
    x_test = x_data[idx[p:]]
    ...  # Similarly for y_train and y_test.

    return x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test
```

Comment: Thanks. If I had known `sklearn.train_test_split()` existed earlier, I would not have reinvent the wheel. Waste of time. Thanks for your answer and highlighting the existence of `sklearn.train_test_split()`. It seems that `sklearn.train_test_split()` achieves the same objective. I will use `sklearn.train_test_split()` instead.

Comment: @user1315789 Sure, you're welcome. For the purpose of this question, let's ignore the existence of that function. Does this do what you originally wanted?

Comment: I'm sure it does. It looks right. I will mark it as the answer when stack overflow allows me to.

Comment: Sorry for posting the dupe. Started writing the answer on mobile before I saw yours.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a mask with `p` randomly selected true elements and index the arrays that way. I would create the mask by shuffling an array of the available indices:

```
ind = np.arange(number_of_samples)
np.random.shuffle(ind)
ind_train = np.sort(ind[:p])
ind_test = np.sort(ind[p:])
x_train = x_data[ind_train]
y_train = y_data[ind_train]
x_test = x_data[ind_test]
y_test = y_data[ind_test]
```

Sorting the indices is only necessary if your original data is monotonically increasing or decreasing in x and you'd like to keep it that way. Otherwise, `ind_train = ind[:p]` is just fine.

Comment: Just curious, why do you sort the indices after selecting them?

Comment: @coldspeed. Added a note. Don't really need to. Was thinking of an unrelated problem I was solving earlier today.